# how to change icon in ant design collapse (Accordian)

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm using ant design accordian for colapse and expand panel , In that instead of up and down arrow I want + and - icon to be display. How can I achieve that

I'm using this one

https://ant.design/components/collapse/

Please help me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can use `expandIcon` prop

https://codepen.io/pen/?&editors=001&prefill_data_id=ab218015-02c4-4c67-9230-2aa590cf5ff3

```
<Collapse
  {...others}
  expandIcon={({ isActive }) => isActive ? <IconYouWant /> : <IconYouWant />}
>
 {children}
</Collapse>
```